# Jquery UI datepicker-bootstrap.js is not working for me

Tags: jquery, angularjs, uidatepicker

I´m using a Jquery UI datepicker in my AngularJS web app. I wanted to replace the PREV and NEXT links with chevrons. So, I found out a clever script called datepicker-bootstrap.js that did that here http://bl.ocks.org/brysonian/3301006#datepicker-bootstrap.js

It´s simple. Only replace some parts of the existing Jquery code with other to add styles and the chevrons.

It half working for me. I mean, I have checked my code and it´s replacing the first four lines. However, it´s not replacing the last two, related with the chevrons:

```
html = html.replace('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w">Prev</span>', '<i class="icon-chevron-left"></i>');
            html = html.replace('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e">Next</span>', '<i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>');
```

I haved copied the part to be replaced `<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w">Prev</span>` and looked for it in the code, just to check if there is a typo, and there it is. So, I don´t know why is not replacing that part.

Comment: why don't you edit in instead of replacing. I mean where you have that `<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w">Prev</span>` in plugin just keep `<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w"><i class="icon-chevron-left"></i></span>`

Comment: you mean to edit the jquery ui-datepicker?

Comment: yea.. do not take the minified version. take the normal js file and try editing that!!

Comment: Well, It could be an approach, but so far, I was just linking to an external jquery source code. I would need to download it.

Comment: Yea.. that will do. but always you should have local copy that can be referred if the application fails to get the file from cdn..